# Expand variable in PowerShell DSC File resource content property

Tags: windows, powershell, dsc

I have $Node.NodeName, $Node.Environment, $Node.Role defined in the following DSC config file. They don't appear to expand to the correct values in the MOF file and instead shows:

```
HOSTNAME: System.Collections.Hashtable
env: System.Collections.Hashtable
role: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

I was expecting each one to expand to the corresponding value as defined under AllNodes. $SQLUser and $SQLPassword display the correct passed in values.

```
CreateDBFile -SQLUser "myuser" -SQLPassword "mypassword" -ConfigurationData inventory.psd1 -OutputPath "C:\DSC"
```

**inventory.psd1**

```
@{

    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName        = "QA-WEB01"
            NodeIP          = "10.48.200.19"
            Role            = "web"
            Environment     = "QA"
        },

        @{
            NodeName        = "QA-WEB02"
            NodeIP          = "10.48.200.20"
            Role            = "Web"
            Environment     = "UAT"
        }
    )
}
```

**CreateDBFile.ps1**

```
Configuration CreateDBFile
{

    param(
        [String]$SQLUser,
        [String]$SQLPassword
    )
    
    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "web" -and $_.NodeIP -contains "10.48.200.19"}.NodeName
    {
        
        File FileExample 
        {
            Ensure           = 'Present'     
            Contents         = "integrations:
- name: nri-mssql
  env:
    HOSTNAME: $Node.NodeName
    USERNAME: $SQLUser
    PASSWORD: $SQLPassword
    PORT: 1433
    ENABLE_SSL: false
    TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: true
    TIMEOUT: 15
  interval: 15s
  labels:
    env: $Node.Environment
    role: $Node.Role
  inventory_source: config/mssql"
            DestinationPath  = 'D:\Logs\\mssql-config.yml'
            Type             = 'File'
        } 
     }

}
```

Comment: The string "System.Collections.Hashtable" is the result of PowerShell evaluating `$Node` as a string. To have it evaluate the property access, use `$()`: `" ... env: $($Node.Environment) ... "`

Comment: Thank you. This is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working CreateDBFile.ps1 file:

```
Configuration CreateDBFile
{

    param(
        [String]$SQLUser,
        [String]$SQLPassword
    )
    
    Node $AllNodes.Where{$_.Role -contains "web" -and $_.NodeIP -contains "10.48.200.19"}.NodeName
    {
        
        File FileExample 
        {
            Ensure           = 'Present'     
            Contents         = "integrations:
- name: nri-mssql
  env:
    HOSTNAME: $($Node.NodeName)
    USERNAME: $SQLUser
    PASSWORD: $SQLPassword
    PORT: 1433
    ENABLE_SSL: false
    TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: true
    TIMEOUT: 15
  interval: 15s
  labels:
    env: $($Node.Environment)
    role: $($Node.Role)
  inventory_source: config/mssql"
            DestinationPath  = 'D:\Logs\\mssql-config.yml'
            Type             = 'File'
        } 
     }
}
```